# Using null coalescing operator with a comparison

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Given the method:

```
public static bool IsDateValid(DateTime? date)
{
    if (date.HasValue ? date.GetValueOrDefault() < MinDate : false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return date.GetValueOrDefault() < MaxDate;
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite the if statement such that it uses the null-coalescing operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace the whole function with

```
return date.GetValueOrDefault() < MaxDate && Date > MinDate;
```

`GetValueOrDefault()` will reutnr an empty `DateTime` (which is `DateTime.MinValue`) if it's null, and that won't be `> MaxDate`.

You can write that explicitly too:

```
return (date ?? DateTime.MinValue) < MaxDate && Date > MinDate;
```

However, you don't even need that:

```
return Date > MinDate && date < MaxDate;
```

Nullable types have lifted comparison operators that return false if an argument is null.

Comment: I guess my desire for using the null-coalescing operator was kind of a red herring.  Your last example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.